# Neural Nets: Benefits of Mixing Activation Functions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, softmax

I'm currently studying and would like to know if there are any actual benefits of using a mixture of activation functions for each layer. For example, if I am trying to predict the probabilities of each class occurring given a certain row of data. A 4 layer network will be implemented having ReLu activation for Hidden layer 1, Sigmoid activation for Hidden layer 2 and finally Softmax activation for the Output Layer.

Since ReLu Activation is used in my 1st hidden layer and as it will only generate 0 and above values, are there any possible benefits of doing this? Maybe the benefit of sparsity for instance?